# Use anchor tag to open a blank window and write into it

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick, htmlwriter

I know that I can use `<a href="" target="_blank">` to open a new window. I can also use `onclick` even handler to create the window and fill it with dynamic content, like `win = open(""); win.document.innerHTML =`. But, the latter forces me to use button and create window explicitly instead of relying on default `<a>` functionality. Can I combine them, to use `<a>` to open the window and it's `onclick` to fill it?

Comment: win.document.write, not innerHTML. And you can use the onclick of a link the same way you use a button

Comment: @mplungjan 1. `win.document.body.innerHTML='abc'` works fine for me. 2. It is not an issue. 3. What does it mean `the same way as button`? Where did I demonstrate using button's href to open a new windo?

Comment: @mplungjan I tried `button onclick="win = window.open('', '_blank'); win.document.body.innerHTML='abc'` and it works. Now, I try to factor out `window.open` into the <a tag>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

win.body.innerHTML only works if you open a page that has a body. Some browsers might do that (open a dummy document) for you, but certainly not all

Here is a link - I use inline JS for demonstration, a better choice is to assign the onclick in onload of the page:

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/btt2xz3a/) since the SO Snippet does not allow the popup

```
<a href="activateyourjsandallowpopups.html" 
onclick="var w = window.open('','_blank'); // may fail if blocked
if (w) { w.document.write('Hello'); w.document.close(); }     
return !w">Click</a>
```

Perhaps you mean this?

```
<a href="pagefrommyserver.html" target="myWin" 
onclick="setTimeout(function() { 
  var w = window.open('','myWin'); // get the opened window handle
  if (w) { w.document.body.innerHTML = 'Hello'}
},200)">Click</a>
```

Comment: I do not get it. Why do you open two windows? Do you understand that I wanted to replace `window.open` with `activateyourjsandallowpopups` rather than to have both of them?

Comment: I do NOT open two windows. If the window.open fails, then I go to the hmtl page that explains that the user needs to allow popups.

Comment: Ok, thanks. It makes sense now. But, it is not what I asked. Probably you say that what I ask is impossible in indirect way.

Comment: Then I do not understand what you ask. What is the exact set of events you want when clicking on the link? A html page opens AND you write something somewhere on the page? Perhaps if you use setTimeout but the page MUST come from the page server as the script

Comment: No, delaying the call does not eliminate it.

Comment: Eliminate what? Remember I still am not sure I understand your use case

Comment: When you replace a thing you add one and eliminate another. When I ask to replace explicit window.open with anchor's click (which naturally opens a window), I ask to eliminate the window.open.

Comment: So the answer to the question assuming I understand it, is no